# How to load all scripts on a website

Tags: jquery, wordpress, nivo-slider

So I have just set up a Nivo slider, although this has now resulted in the rest of the scripts from not working.  I am unable to edit where the nivo slider loads, as it is a plugin, but I need to force those scripts to load before the websites, otherwise, no posts show up?

I am at a loss on how to do this and its the last thing i need to do inregards to this website.. so desperate to get it over and done with. haha

Here is the page in question: http://hobhob.co.uk/whmag/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're an administrator on your WordPress site, you can edit the plugin using the [plugin editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugins_Editor_Screen). I would recommend to look for how the Nivo slider calls its JS files by searching for the [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function as that is the recommended way for loading JS files.

Also, most plugin developers should take into account other JS files in a WordPress environment when developing a plugin, so the problem may not necessarily be with the slider plugin, but some other JS file that you're loading. Using process of elimination, try disabling plugins one by one and see if any others are causing problems.

Good luck!

Comment: Ace, thanks a lot, so I guess if i remove the script loads in the plugin, I should be able to load them in my own order?.. here is hoping this works.. thanks! :)

Comment: Amazing it worked!  I removed the code from the plugins 'show' scripting file, and only removed the script calls, not any of the CSS code and then added this to the themes header file and done, all now displays correctly! :) Thanks for the tip! Huge help!